# Neither 'MongoDB\Client' or 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017")' work

Tags: php, mongodb, mamp

I am trying to install the mongoDB extension for PHP with MAMP so I can potentially access my MongoDB server, and as far as I can tell, I have done everything right, yet I am still getting errors.

I have the MongoDB extension installed - I can tell because:

```
$sudo pecl install mongodb
pecl/mongodb is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.5.3
install failed
```

Also my phpinfo shows this:

[image: php mongodb extension]

Also I have included the following:

```
var_dump(extension_loaded('mongodb'));
echo phpversion('mongodb')."\n";
```

which have returned:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mongo.php:35:boolean true
1.5.3
```

I also have:

```
$ composer require mongodb/mongodb
Using version ^1.4 for mongodb/mongodb
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

phpinfo tells me my php.ini file is here:

[image: location of php ini file]

And i have added to that:

```
extension=mongodb.so
```

In my PHP file I have the following:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // include Composer's autoloader
$m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
//$m = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");

echo "connected successfully";

// select a database
$db = $m->bob;
echo "database selected";
```

If I try the MongDB/Client option, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\Client' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mongo.php on line 61
```

If I try the MongoDB/Driver option, I get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: MongoDB\Driver\Manager::$bob in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mongo.php on line 52
```

A var_dump of MongoDB\Driver etc. gives the following:

```
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mongo.php:38:
 object(MongoDB\Driver\Manager)[3]
 public 'uri' => string 'mongodb://localhost:27017' (length=25)
 public 'cluster' => 
    array (size=0)
    empty
```

Is there anything I could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

have you added    `extension=mongodb.so` to your php.ini file ?

that is the only information i do not see listed here.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have that as well. I will add the info about that above.

Comment: could you try mongo.so instead of mongodb.so. it might help ( diffently not sure)

Comment: Isn't that deprecated? mongodb then disappears from my phpinfo and it now says Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found.

Comment: oh yes. (forgot to look at mongodb version)

then i cant help you further i think. maybe try a guide or something to follow and create a testproject so you can compare the one that works vs this one.

Comment: Not sure if allowed but I have tried some alternate code and I believe this is a step further but have a new problem, which I have asked here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669717/mongodb-exception-server-reports-wire-version-0-but-version-of-libmongoc-requi