# How to install older version of mongolite using URL with tar.gz?

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

I use R version `3.6.2` and I installed `mongolite` as follows:

```
install.packages("mongolite")
```

Then I tried to connect to my MongoDB server as follows (from R):

```
con <- mongo(url="xxx", collection = "tescollection", db="testdb", verbose = TRUE)
```

However, it fails with the following error message:

> Server at xxx:11155 reports wire version 2, but this version of
>   libmongoc requires at least 3 (MongoDB 3.0)

How can I fix this issue without changing the server's MongoDB version?

I found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669717/mongodb-exception-server-reports-wire-version-0-but-version-of-libmongoc-requi) for `php`, but I am using `R`.

I tried to install an earlier version of `mongolite` as follows, but then it says `package ‘mongolite’ is not available (for R version 3.6.2)`:

```
install.packages("mongolite", repo="https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mongolite/mongolite_1.6.tar.gz", lib="library")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `devtools` should do the trick

```
devtools::install_version("mongolite", version = "1.6")
```

Comment: can I install it into a specific folder, in my case `library`?

Comment: @Fluxy In the documentation it states `... Other arguments passed on to utils::install.packages().` So you might be able to pass `lib = lib`